# Reading and writing text in different languages from a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, google-translate

I'm trying to translate words into another languages ( like Hindi , Chinese , Russian , etc. ) and store them in a .txt file . I have successfully encoded the data and written it in the file , but I am unable to read it the same way .

For example , if I translate "me" into hindi , I get "मुझे" as the result ( which is good ) . Also , the same gets printed in my file . But I am unable to extract it the same way .

Text written in file : me (English) : (Hindi) मुझे

How I wanted it to be extracted : me (English) : (Hindi) मुझे

How I get it : ÿþme (English) : (Hindi) .      A       ↔       G

Screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Code :

```
import googletrans as GT

text = "me"

translator = GT.Translator()
raw_trans = translator.translate(text, dest="hi", src="en")
translation = raw_trans.text

print(f"Translation : {translation}")

with open("lango.txt", "wb") as writer:
    information = f"{text} (English) : (Hindi) {translation}"
    info = information.encode(encoding="utf-16")
    writer.write(info)

with open("lango.txt", "r") as reader:
    correct_info = reader.read()
    print(correct_info)
```

Please help me regarding this .

Comment: `ÿþ` is [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of `utf-16-le`  interpreted in `cp1252` (see [Byte order marks by encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding)).

Comment: Please don't post barely readable images of text.  Copy and paste the actual text.  It's helpful for screen readers and to allow us to copy the text for use in answer examples.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the encoding that you are opening the file in is a different encoding from the one you save it in (UTF-16).

When you don't specify an encoding in `open("lango.txt", "r")`, Python uses the default system encoding. On Linux and Mac this is UTF-8, and on Windows this is usually a legacy encoding depending on the language used (for example, if the language is set to Japanese it is Microsoft's version of Shift-JIS). Whatever platform you are using, then, it is very likely that when you open the file you are not opening it in UTF-16.

The long and the short of it is, you should specify the encoding both when you save the file and when you open it again. And these days, I would recommend that you use UTF-8, as it has become the de-facto standard for encoding on the web and elsewhere.

For example, you could use the following code:

```
import googletrans as GT

text = "me"

translator = GT.Translator()
raw_trans = translator.translate(text, dest="hi", src="en")
translation = raw_trans.text

print(f"Translation : {translation}")

with open("lango.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(f"{text} (English) : (Hindi) {translation}")

with open("lango.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

For a good background on how encodings work, see Joel Spolsky's blog post [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)